# How to write sql query in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader, pandasql

How to write the below query in pandas data frame

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE a = "S"
AND b IS NOT NULL
AND c IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an equivalent command to get the same result in a pandas dataframe, you can try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['S','T','S'],'b':[None, 1, 2],'c':[1,2,3]})
df = df.dropna(subset=['b','c'])
df.loc[df.dropna(subset=['b','c'])['a'] == 'S']
```

Original dataframe

```
   a    b  c
0  S  NaN  1
1  T  1.0  2
2  S  2.0  3
```

Output

```
    a   b   c
2   S   2.0 3
```

Comment: i have applied the below logic 
df.loc[df.dropna(subset=['b','c'])['a'] == 'S']
but 'a' columns values are not filtering as S .i am getting other than 's' values